How to display text beside marker in Google maps in Jetpack Compose
I am using Google Maps in my jetpack compose project. I want to display text beside the marker. I tried using Marker() it shows a marker but not text. It shows text when I click on the marker but I want it to show text with a marker.
    GoogleMap(
    googleMapOptionsFactory = {
        GoogleMapOptions().mapId(MapDefaults.mapId)
    },
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
    properties = style.mapProperties,
    uiSettings = style.mapUiSettings,
    onMapClick = onMapClick,
    onMapLoaded = onMapLoaded,
) {
    Marker(
        state = MarkerState(position = LatLng(latitude, longitude)),
        title = "Your Marker Title",
        snippet = "Text beside the icon",
        icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.your_icon)
    )
}


Use showInfoWindow like this
val markerState = rememberMarkerState(null, LatLng(latitude, longitude))
Marker(
    state = markerState,
    title = "Your Marker Title",
    snippet = "Text beside the icon",
    icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.your_icon)
)

markerStatearkerState.showInfoWindow()

